# RDLC - Displaying data based on condition using reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I'm looking for the way to control how the address information is displayed in different situations.

1st situation happens when Address1 and Address2 fields exist

```
First Name
ATT: John Doe
1000 Main Street
New York, NY 10001
```

where Address1 is ATT: John Doe and Address2 is 1000 Main Street

2nd situation happens when Address1 does not exist:

```
First Name
1000 Main Street
New York, NY 10001
```

where Address2 is 1000 Main Street

And I have the following logic defined in the report:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!Address1.Value, "MyStoredProc")),"",First(Fields!Address2.Value,"MyStoredProc"))
```

That logic displays the following:

```
First Name
1000 Main Street
New York, NY 10001
```

However, it should display that:

```
First Name
ATT: John Doe
1000 Main Street
New York, NY 10001
```

Since, Address1 data exists in the database.

So, basically, I want to display Address1 only if it exists.

Or in other words,

when Address1 exists I need to display the following:

```
First Name
ATT: John Doe
1000 Main Street
New York, NY 10001
```

when Address1 does not exist, I need to display the following:

```
First Name
1000 Main Street
New York, NY 10001
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!Address1.Value, "MyStoredProc")),
 "", First(Fields!Address1.Value, "MyStoredProc") & " - ") & First(Fields!Address2.Value, "MyStoredProc")
```

**Update:** Expression edition based on user feed.

I don't know how are you arranging data in the report I am assuming you are concatenating multiple fields in textbox but I am not sure.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!Address1.Value, "MyStoredProc")) or
First(Fields!Address1.Value, "MyStoredProc") = "",
"", First(Fields!Address1.Value, "MyStoredProc") & VbCrLf) & First(Fields!Address2.Value, "MyStoredProc")
```

I've added a validation for empty string field (`""`). Also I added a new line character `VbCrLf` to put the second address2 in the next line if address1 exists.

Let me know if this was helpful.